# How to tell pylint that class instance variable is not a constant

Tags: python, python-2.7, pylint

```
class MyFavoriteClass():
  def __init__(self):
      self.counter = 0
  def memberFunction(self):
      self.counter = self.counter + 1

myinstance = MyFavoriteClass() #Pylint complains here
myinstance.memberFunction()
```

The error reported by pylint for the second to last line is

```
[C0103] Invalid name "myinstance" for type constant (should match (([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)|(__.*__))$)
```

I have read that it is possible to disable this type of error entirely, but is it necessary?

How can I tell pylint that myinstance is not a constant?

System configuration reported by pylint -v

```
pylint 0.26.0, 
astng 0.24.1, common 0.59.1
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With *pylint*, you can ignore individual errors, warnings, etc. on a line by using a special comment of the format: `# pylint: disable={comma-separated-list-of-names-or-codes}`

```
class MyFavoriteClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
    def memberFunction(self):
        self.counter = self.counter + 1

myinstance = MyFavoriteClass() # pylint: disable=invalid-name
myinstance.memberFunction()
```

Or, you can specify a list of message codes to ignore in the pylint config file:

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]

# Disable the message, report, category or checker with the given id(s). You
# can either give multiple identifier separated by comma (,) or put this option
# multiple time (only on the command line, not in the configuration file where
# it should appear only once).
disable=invalid-name
# OR
disable=C0103
```

NOTE: Disabling a code from the config file will ignore it globally. If you want to just ignore it on a specific line, you'll have to use the special comment mentioned at the beginning.

The pylint config file is determined by first checking the `PYLINTRC` environment variable. If that does not provide a file, then `~/.pylintrc` and `/etc/pylintrc` are checked consecutively.

If you can control the *pylint* command being executed, you can also specify the config using the `--rcfile` parameter.

If you'd like to generate a sample config, run:

```
pylint --generate-rcfile
```

Additionally, if you disable a code, that will trigger [`locally-disabled (I0011)`](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:i0011) which itself can also disabled (ideally in the config).

Comment: o boy.. nothing more fun than having obscure non-human-readable comments to satisfy the machine =P

Comment: I'll give another solution in a sec

Comment: @Claudiu that's why those  numerical ids are to be replaced with symbolic name, eg use 'invalid-name' rather than C0103

Comment: After the change the error becomes: 
    I:  7,0: Locally disabling C0103.  Good

Comment: @JonnyRo If you want to ignore `I0011`, you can always disable it in the config.